# Mouse events on Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, mouseevent

I want in the window of a wpf to set a treeview and make use of it through mouse events. Particularly, I would like a complex shape to be drawn on a canvas by a mouseclick on each item of the treeview. However I am not sure if the treeview can serve this purpose, since the implementation I made does not seem to work at all. The mouse events do not work (the delegates are not triggered). Could someone indicate me the reason? Have a look at the code:

```
<TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Input Data">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Vector" MouseEnter="create_Rhombus"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Array"/>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Maths">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Add" MouseDown="create_AddRectangle"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Subtract" MouseDown="create_SubtractRectangle"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Multiply" MouseDown="create_MultiplyRectangle"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Divide" MouseDown="create_DivideRectangle"/>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The methods in the code behind file are:

```
private void create_AddRectangle(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

private void create_SubtractRectangle(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

….

However the above methods are not invoked. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is presumably because of the selection functionality, the mouse event is being marked as handled internally. Try using the [tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) versions of such events (i.e. `PreviewMouseDown`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a bug with using tunneling (ie `PreviewMouseDown`). I implemented it and it fires correctly but if I try to access the DataContext I get a `{DisconnectedItem}` object. From the reading I've done online, this appears to be a bug with WPF.

I did find that I can wire a `MouseLeftButtonDown` and a `MouseRightButtonDown` events for a single `TreeViewItem` to the same method and it will work exactly the same way you'd expect the `MouseDown` event to work.